# how to change the position of uiimageview in a textview while editing the text

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uitextview

I am making an app in which ,i have to put images in uitextview.
Problem i am facing is that when i write text in the middle of two images then how can i shift the image accordingly . 
Any sample code will be appreciated .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here i am providing you sample code for one image.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
if ( [text isEqualToString:@"\n"] ) {

}
else
{
    NSString *yourstring = [[NSString alloc]init];
    yourstring = textView.text;
    CGSize s = [yourstring sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] //define your textview font size
                      constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, MAXFLOAT)  // - 40 For cell padding
                          lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];   
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, s.height+10, 320.0f, 20);//use YourImageView. height and width 
    YourImageView.frame=frame;
}
return YES;
}
```

Hope, this will help you..